# Core dump in solaris

Tags: solaris, dump, solaris-10

I am getting below error while running an executable in solaris :**Illegal Instruction (core dumped)**

When i use pstack command to check the core file i get below info: 
**ffffffff7f501f20 ???????? (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
 0000000000000000 ???????? (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
pstack: warning: librtld_db failed to initialize; symbols from shared libraries will not be available**

I have compiled the makefiles in different linux and generated executable and tried running there and it is running successfully without any issues.
could someone please let me know how to resolve this as the issue is coming only in Solaris.

Comment: First, do you have a limit on core file size set?  If so, remove it.  The only useful core file size limits are `0` to suppress all core file creation and `unlimited` to allow creation of a file that isn't truncated.  (The last time I checked - Solaris writes the stack information **last** into a core file, so if it's truncated at all it's completely useless).  Also post the full command used to compile and link your code.